# Javascript two "For" cycle loop to get data from 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, for-loop

I have three arrays one title array with 10 elements, 2nd  subtitle array with 121 elements and 3rd  description array with 121 elements, i need to display it in a list where i put in this format:

```
  ---Title
    ---subtitle[0]----listequivalent[0]
    ----subtitle[1]-----list equivalent[1]
    ---subtitle..etc
    ---------------------
    ----title 2
   ---- subtitleofthis[2]-----descriptionEquivalent[2]   
    ----subtitleofthis[3]-----descriotionEquivalent[3] subtitleofthis...etc
    ---------------------
```

i have this:

```
   for(var j=0;j<titles.length;j++){

    $("#divisionTitles").append("<div  class='content-block-title'>" + titles[j] + "</div>");


   for(var i=0;i<subtitle.length;i++){


    $("#divisionTitles").append(" <ul>"+
            "<li class='item-link item-content'>"+
            " <a href='=" + description[i] +"'"  + ">"+
    "<div class='item-inner'>"+
     "<div class='item-title'>"+ subtitle[i] +"</div>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</a>"+
    "</li>"+
    "</ul>");

  }
}
```

but it shows like this:

```
---title
---subtitle[all] //all from 1 to 121 with the descriptions 1 to 121
--- title 2
--- subtitle[all] //all from 1 to 121 with the descriptions 1 to 121
```

Comment: Is there anything, in any of the arrays, that would tell you which subtitles go with which titles? Can you *show* us some of each array? Otherwise, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: How are these arrays related? How do you know a sub-title correspondent to a specific title?

Comment: im just relating by the number, it is in order 1 to 121 and the subtitle 1 is the description 1 etc.. but i dont have something to relate to title maybe thats my error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's exactly what are you telling it to do - "translated" it to more human language, it'll look something like:

`for each title print all the subtitles`

You would need something like

`fore each title print all the MATCHING subtitles`

that means you would have to change your structure a bit (eg. have array where each element of such array would be object containing `title` and another array containing every matching subtitles)

Or if you for some reason need to preserve your structure you may do something like this:

```
for each title do following:
    read all the subtitles and if it's matching print it
```

that means you will add one `if` in your inner `for`, that means it'll be looking like this:

```
for(var j=0;j<titles.length;j++){

    $("#divisionTitles").append("<div  class='content-block-title'>" + titles[j] + "</div>");


   for(var i=0;i<subtitle.length;i++){


       if(subtitle is matching) {
           /* I don't know how the code should find out which
            * title does this subtitle matching because of this
            * i'm not putting exact code in the if but only a psedocode
            */


         /*** do your stuff here ***/
       }
   }
}
```